# Google site script api giving null value

Tags: google-apps-script

Is somebody facing the same problem regarding Google script sites api not working correctly?

`SitesApp.getActivePage()` is returning null?

`var activePage = SitesApp.getActivePage().getUrl();`
is not giving results but some days ago it was working properly.

Comment: SitesApp.getActivePage() => Returns the active page, if the script is hosted in a container, or null otherwise.
read the doc here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/sites-app